# How to delete quotation mark in text file printed

Tags: text-files, double-quotes, scilab

I'm honestly a novice on scilab.
I'm using `print` function to create .txt file with my character matrix in it.
But , when I open txt file, double quote appeared. I just want words without "".
This is how I'm using `print`

```
Compterendu(1,1)= "Medecin demandeur: " 
fileresname= fullfile(RES_PATH, "compterendu.txt") 
print(fileresname,Compterendu)
```

And, [compterendu.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPcyA.jpg) was printed out like this.

Would be so grateful for any help!!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use "print" ? After looking into the doc, yes, it is used to produce the same text as when you type the expression or the variable name on the command line. Hence it *does* print double quotes for strings. If you need something more basic use lower level i/o commands, like `mputl`.

S.

Comment: Yes I tried to open the file on scinotes, double quote disappeared. But when I try to open it with an another text file editor, double quote still there. Please could you explain why ? Do I have to change the content of the file from Scilab command line?

Comment: I updated my answer. Don't use `print` for basic i/o stuff.

Comment: Great ! Can you validate my answer ?